# Resulting output is different than the desired one, what to do?

Tags: output

I am trying to use the following code to create a titlepage named `\titleHGP`.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\ifpdf
  \usepackage{pdfcolmk}
\fi
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pifont}
\ifxetex
  \usepackage{fontspec}
\fi

%\usepackage{pst-text}

%%%% Additional font macros
\makeatletter
%%%% light series
%% e.g., s:12
\DeclareRobustCommand\ltseries
  {\not@math@alphabet\ltseries\relax
   \fontseries\ltdefault\selectfont}
%% e.g., t:32
\newcommand{\ltdefault}{l}
%% e.g., v:19
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textlt}{\ltseries}

% heavy(bold) series
\DeclareRobustCommand\hbseries
  {\not@math@alphabet\hbseries\relax
   \fontseries\hbdefault\selectfont}
%% e.g., t:32
\newcommand{\hbdefault}{hb}
%% e.g., v:19
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\texthb}{\hbseries}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\isbn}{{\small\textsc{ISBN}}}

%%% for the Web-O-Mints fonts
\newcommand*{\wb}[2]{\fontsize{#1}{#2}\usefont{U}{webo}{xl}{n}}
%\renewcommand*{\wb}[2]{}%    probably kills Web-O-Mints (and some layouts?)
%%% for the Fontsite 500 fonts
\newcommand*{\FSfont}[1]{%
  \fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{#1}\selectfont}
%\renewcommand*{\FSfont}[1]{}%    kills special font selections

\newcommand*{\labelit}[1]{\phantomsection\label{#1}}
\newcommand*{\refit}[1]{(graphic on page~\pageref{#1})}

\chapterstyle{dash}\renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\itshape\LARGE}
\setlength{\beforechapskip}{2\onelineskip}
\setsecheadstyle{\normalfont\Large\raggedright}
\makeindex
\renewcommand*{\indexname}{Index of Designers}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\boxminipage}{%
  \@ifnextchar [%]
    \@ibxminipage
    {\@iiibxminipage c\relax[s]}}
\def\@ibxminipage[#1]{%
  \@ifnextchar [%]
    {\@iibxminipage{#1}}%
    {\@iiibxminipage{#1}\relax[s]}}
\def\@iibxminipage#1[#2]{%
  \@ifnextchar [%]
    {\@iiibxminipage{#1}{#2}}%
    {\@iiibxminipage{#1}{#2}[#1]}}
\let\@bxminto\@empty
\def\@iiibxminipage#1#2[#3]#4{%
  \ifx\relax#2\else
    \setlength\@tempdimb{#2}%
    \def\@bxminto{to\@tempdimb}%
  \fi
  \leavevmode
  \@pboxswfalse
  \if #1b\vbox
  \else
    \if #1t\vtop
    \else
      \ifmmode \vcenter
      \else \@pboxswtrue $\vcenter
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
%  \@bxminto
  \bgroup%          outermost vbox
    \hsize #4
    \hrule\@height\fboxrule
    \hbox\bgroup%   inner hbox
      \vrule\@width\fboxrule \hskip\fboxsep 
    \vbox \@bxminto
    \bgroup% innermost vbox
    \vskip\fboxsep
    \advance\hsize -2\fboxrule \advance\hsize -2\fboxsep
    \textwidth\hsize \columnwidth\hsize
    \@parboxrestore
    \def\@mpfn{mpfootnote}\def\thempfn{\thempfootnote}\c@mpfootnote\z@
    \let\@footnotetext\@mpfootnotetext
    \let\@listdepth\@mplistdepth \@mplistdepth\z@
    \@minipagerestore\@minipagetrue
    \everypar{\global\@minipagefalse\everypar{}}}

\def\endboxminipage{%
  \par\vskip-\lastskip
  \ifvoid\@mpfootins\else
    \vskip\skip\@mpfootins\footnoterule\unvbox\@mpfootins\fi
   \vskip\fboxsep
  \egroup%    end innermost vbox
  \hskip\fboxsep \vrule\@width\fboxrule
  \egroup%    end hbox
  \hrule\@height\fboxrule
  \egroup%    end outermost vbox
  \if@pboxsw $\fi}
\makeatother

\DeclareRobustCommand{\cs}[1]{\texttt{\char`\\#1}}
\newlength{\tpheight}\setlength{\tpheight}{0.9\textheight}
\newlength{\txtheight}\setlength{\txtheight}{0.9\tpheight}
\newlength{\tpwidth}\setlength{\tpwidth}{0.9\textwidth}
\newlength{\txtwidth}\setlength{\txtwidth}{0.9\tpwidth}
\newlength{\drop}

\newenvironment{showtitle}{%
  \begin{boxminipage}[c][\tpheight]{\tpwidth}
  \centering\begin{vplace}\begin{minipage}[c][\txtheight]{\txtwidth}}%
{\end{minipage}\end{vplace}\end{boxminipage}}

\definecolor{Dark}{gray}{.2}
\definecolor{MedDark}{gray}{.4}
\definecolor{Medium}{gray}{.6}
\definecolor{Light}{gray}{.8}
\newcommand*{\titleHGP}{\begingroup% Handy Guide to Papermaking
\drop=0.1\txtheight
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.05\txtwidth}
  \color{Red}
  \rule{6pt}{\txtheight}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{0.05\txtwidth}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\txtwidth}
  \vspace*{\drop}
  {\Large THE AUTHOR} \\
  \rule{0.9\txtwidth}{1pt} \par
  \vspace{3\baselineskip}
  {\noindent\Huge\bfseries CONUNDRUMS} \par
  \vspace{2\baselineskip}
  {\Large\itshape A Handy Guide to Puzzles and Enigmas} \par
  \vspace{6.5\baselineskip}
  {\scshape after the foreign edition of year \\
   translated by} \par
\vspace{0.1\baselineskip}
  {\Large THE TRANSLATOR} \par
  \vspace{\baselineskip}
  \rule{0.9\txtwidth}{1pt} \par
  \vspace{\baselineskip}
  {\Large THE PUBLISHER}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.15\txtwidth}
  {\color{Red} 
  \FSfont{5fh}% FontSite Fette Gotisch
  \HUGE
  \vspace{3.3\baselineskip}
    H \\[1.15\baselineskip]
    G \\[1.15\baselineskip]
    P \\[1.15\baselineskip]
    E
}\par
  \vspace{4\baselineskip}
  {\Large YEAR}
\end{minipage}
\endgroup}
\begin{document}
\titleHGP
\end{document}
```

but the output comes out to be,
[image]
instead of,
[image]
How can I get the later ouput?

Comment: Your code contains `\FSfont{5fh}` to load the special fontfamily.  It looks like your system failed to detect this font.

Comment: Also, if you want the big red letters moved left, either lose the \hfill or increase the width of the minipage containing them.